# Plus and Minus not showing on input Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, input, icons, woocommerce

The plus and minus icons / signs aren't showing in my buttons and I'm super stumped as to why?

The page in question is here:
http://rainbowquran.co.uk/product/small-quran-soft-purple/

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the plus/minus icons because of the following line in the style.css

```
text-indent: -9999px;
```

It is in the following style:

```
.minus, .plus 
{
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 20px!important;
    height: 31px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: 8px 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Removing that from the style should work.

Comment: Np, if you want you can mark the answer as correct so other users who had the same problem as you did will know hoe you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your CSS property in style.css.
On line number 1060, remove this property:

```
    text-indent: -9999px;
```